# Assign dynamic values to JavaScript dictionary

Tags: javascript, dictionary, echarts

I need to assign dynamic values to JavaScript dictionary to be used to echarts but when assigning the dynamic values to dictionary it is showing the different behavior as compare to assigning the static values.

when assigning static values :

```
     response = {
            "stacks": {"5G_L2": [{"Open": "43"},{"Close": "24"}],
                       "5G_L3": [{"Open": "12"},{"Close": "2"}]
                      }
                  };
```

Debug window showing like :

[image]

whereas when assigning the values dynamically like as below :

```
            var datastck=[];
            var serverdata = '{{ barCdata | tojson }}';
            resPbar = $.parseJSON(serverdata);

            $.each(resPbar, function (i, item) {
              var di={};
              di[item.Team]=[{"Open": item.Open},{"Close": item.Close}];
              datastck.push(di);
            });

            
          response = {
            "stacks": datastck
                  };
```

Debug window be like :

[image]

it is adding one extra layer of array .I need to have the static assignment structure to support the echarts, Someone Advice please?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: console always shows indexes of Arrays - is that what your other question was about? Yes, Arrays are just objects ... each item has an index as the key

Comment: If you want `stacks` to be an object (or as you call it, a dictionary) like in your static example, then in your dynamic approach you should be setting it to an object. Currently you're setting it to `datastck` which is an array. Remove the array and move `var di={};` outside of the loop, then assign the `stacks` property to `di`.

Comment: If you are explicitly pushing items into an array, then you must not wonder, when you get an array as result ... You want `var datastck={};`, and then nothing but `datastck[item.Team]=[{"Open": item.Open},{"Close": item.Close}];` inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var serverdata = '{{ barCdata | tojson }}';
resPbar = $.parseJSON(serverdata);

var response = {
    "stacks": {}
};

$.each(resPbar, function (i, item) {
    response.stacks[item.Team].push({
        "Open": item.Open,
        "Close": item.Close
    });
});
```

Comment: `stacks[item.Team].push(` will not work since `stacks[item.Team]` won't be an array (at least on the initial set of that property), it should (most likely) be `stacks[item.Team] =` (assuming `item.Team` is unique, which it seems like in OPs code)

Comment: You are right! `response.stacks[item.Team] = [{` should work fine, as you say